# Using rpath from a dynamic library

Tags: macos, qt, dynamic-linking, dynamic-library

Rpath are traditionally defined in the application executable.

Is it possible though to define additional additional rpath for a specific dynamic library, so that all the other dynamic libraries that this dynamic library needs will be searched according to the rpath defined in this dynamic library?

The reason I'm asking is because I don't have any control over the executable, but I'm developing a plugin for that executable that needs to access a framework to work (the Qt framework, which is distributed as a set of dynamic libraries, so I'll deploy it in the same folder as the plugin). The platform I'm targeting is macOs.